# Programming noob with an issue

Tags: php, css, include

My name is Pete and I have a question for the masses. I am using the code found on Thomas J Bradley's site for a project at work. It's a signature acceptance application that turns a signature (from a tablet device) to a png file for doing whatever. It works, but I have a modification I would like to do to it. Here's the site:

http://managercheckoff.oo3.co/home.html

I'll be fixing the css and branding it and such for my application; this is a working copy. What I would like it to do is save the png file with a filename I enter in the "store name" box. In other words, if I enter "store10" in the box, I want my png file to be named store10.png. Here's the code for the site:

(begin code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Accept a Signature · Signature Pad</title>
  <style>
    body { font: normal 100.01%/1.375 "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
  </style>
  <link href="./assets/jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="./assets/flashcanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <form method="post" action="" class="sigPad">
    <label for="name">Store Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">

    <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
    <ul class="sigNav">

      <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it" >Draw It</a></li>
      <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sig sigWrapper">
      <div class="typed"></div>
      <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
      <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit.</button>

<?php
    // this is the part that writes outout
    require_once 'signature-to-image.php';

$json = $_POST['output'];
$img = sigJsonToImage($json);

imagepng($img, 'signature.png');

  ?>
</form>

  <script src="jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});
    });
  </script>
  <script src="./assets/json2.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

(end code)

If anyone could help I would appreciate it. I am just learning, and I wish it wasn't under these circumstances (work related) but I don't have a choice. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should consider looking into a file I/O API

Comment: Don't know about that library, but I'm pretty sure you need to look at this: **imagepng($img, 'signature.png');** Instead of signature.png enter your desired filename

Comment: Thank you Dexa, I can change the name of the file to whatever.png and that's how it is saved, and it works. I was looking for the ability to make the filename what is entered in the box at the top of the page. Ponsicte and Michael made a suggestion below that I'm going to try. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to change this in order to pass to `imagepng` function a variable which contains the `filename`

```
imagepng($img, 'signature.png');
```

so it would be

```
$ext = array();
$ext['png'] = '.png';

// in case you entered a name in your "store name" box it will be assigned as filename, otherwise, 'signature' will be the default name
$filename = ((isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : 'signature') . $ext['png'];
imagepng($img, $filename);
```

**NOTE**

`$ext` is an array, you can add all the extension you want and in the future your code will be easy to manage in case you'll handle for example also `imagejpeg` function.

hope this helps :-)

Comment: I would suggest some further changes, concatenate .png to the end of that POST - make sure the filename includes the extension without having to rely on the user to provide it.

So if the user enters filename, the server makes filename.png

Comment: It would probably be best to make the post and extension concatenation a variable, then call the variable in imagepng()

Comment: @Michael fixed and added a few useful things. Thanks for your advice :-)

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I'm going to try it and let everyone know if it works.

Comment: The naming convention works great! That's really cool thank you :) I'm working on making the extension part of it work. The file is being saved, and I can even save it as whatever name I want, I just can't append the .png extension to it.

Comment: @user3468549 sorry, my fault, i forgot a `(` and a `)`. I edited the code, now it works! :-)

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks again. Beers on me if I ever get the chance. Cheers!